# How can I combine these two formulas together?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get this formula to work on the I18 cell. How will that look in one line? I'm currently getting an error.

This is what I'm trying:

```
=SUMIF(G218-H218,">0")&=IF(I18<=0,"ALL KEYS SOLD", "")
```

Comment: sumif returns a numeric value, the & operator assumes string concatenation, and you've got an extra `=` after it also. At this point, not really clear what you're trying to do, perhaps if you can share some example data and the expected output, it would better illustrate the problem?

Comment: @DavidZemens What I'm trying to do is in cell I218 write a formula that will display the result of G218-H218 however if the answer is 0 or a negative number then it should displays "ALL KEYS SOLD" instead of 0.

Comment: `=IF(G218-H218<=0,"ALL KEYS SOLD",G218-H218)`.

Comment: @BigBen the only problem of this way is that when G218-H218 are blank then I218 shows "ALL KEYS SOLD" and in that case if those are blank then I will want it to stay blank and not display "ALL KEYS SOLD". Only display the text when its equal to 0 or a negative number.

Comment: @AlfredoNatal - Please [edit] that requirement/stipulation into your question.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need two formulas:

```
=IF(G218-H218<=0;"ALL KEYS SOLD";G218-H218)
```

Comment: The only problem of this way is that when G218-H218 are blank then I218 shows "ALL KEYS SOLD" and in that case if those are blank then I will want it to stay blank and not display "ALL KEYS SOLD". Only display the text when its equal to 0 or a negative number.

Comment: @AlfredoNatal You can chain `IF` statements inside each other, like so: `IF(LEN(G218 & H218)<1, "", IF(G218-H218<=0, "ALL KEYS SOLD", G218-H218))`